# Is it possible to get pie series colours from pie chart at the run time?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Im trying to get colours of the pie chart at the run time. I'm using this method.but this methos is not working.

```
            var allSeries:Array = s1.getStyle("fills");

            Alert.show(allSeries[0].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the API to get colours of the pie chart at the run time, so i debuged it, and get this way,hope to useful.

```
var items:Array =chart.getItemsInRegion(chart.getVisibleRect());
for each(var item:PieSeriesItem in items){
    var fill:SolidColor = SolidColor(item.fill);
    Alert.show(fill.color+"");
}
```

PS：this color is decimal system.

Comment: thank you for your reply . But the problem is the value return from this code is not giving actual hexadecimal value of the colours used in the chart. this code returns decimal number and i converted that number into hexadecimal to check whether colour codes are same or not. But values are totally different.

Comment: Do you consider the alpha in SolidColor? I checked the value is OK.
<mx:PieChart itemClick="regionChange(event.hitData.item)">, I think you can get what you want in this event.hitData.item parameter.

Comment: Im trying to get used colours of the piechart without hitting piechart.actually my target is to get used colours in to array.that array of colours im using for create seperate legend component.